# jQuery trigger click not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

The following works in Chrome and HTML--it clicks five separate elements on page load. IE8 doesn't throw any error, but the click event does not happen. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    var1=document.getElementById("agencyautoclick")
    $(var1).trigger('click');
    var2=document.getElementById("scaleautoclick")
    $(var2).trigger('click');
    var3=document.getElementById("modeautoclick")
    $(var3).trigger('click');
    var4=document.getElementById("infrastructureautoclick")
    $(var4).trigger('click');
    var5=document.getElementById("topicsautoclick")
    $(var5).trigger('click');
    });
    }
</script>
```

I originally wasn't using jQuery (just used .click()), but that again did not work in IE8.

Answer (score 3):

All you have written is the same as:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#agencyautoclick').trigger('click');
  $('#scaleautoclick').trigger('click');
  $('#modeautoclick').trigger('click');
  $('#infrastructureautoclick').trigger('click');
  $('#topicsautoclick').trigger('click');
});   
</script>
```

You are not taking advantage of jQuery =)

Answer (score 2):

don't do

```
var1=document.getElementById("agencyautoclick")
$(var1).trigger('click');
```

do

```
var $var1 = $('#agencyautoclick');

// OR

var $var1 = document.getElementById('agencyautoclick');
```

and don't forget the semicolon ";" end the end of EACH complete command (line).

further

```
window.onload = function(){
    $(document).ready(function() { /* ... */ });
};
```

is not good.
You have to decide if you want to load the function on window-load or if you want to load it on document-ready.

just write

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { /* ... */ });

    // OR

    $(window).load(function() { /* ... */ });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but IE8 doesn't seem to like any of them. Oy vey.

Comment: Post your according HTML-Code... Maybe there is the mistake